# xdebug and Eclipse PDT debugging options

Tags: eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I recently got xdebug working with my Eclipse PDT and MAMP setup. I just opened a file to edit and it's riddled with errors. Upon closer inspection these errors are mostly a) Invalid Function Name (use setMessage instead of SetMessage) and b) formatting issues 
expected `} else {` instead of 

}
else
{

So the question is, is there a way to change these settings?  Would this be handled by the code formatting settings of PDT or is it specific to xdebug?

Changing the coding style of this project is not really an option at this point, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: ? ... I am a bit confused ... you seem to be refering to coding standards ... I have no idea what that has got to do with XDebug.

Comment: Turns out I was confused.  I had assumed the changes were due to enabling xdebug and debugging in PDT, but it looks like I had enabled a different validation tool as well.  That tool is what was showing the code formatting errors.